# Confusion in +v -v and ground in amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, circuit-protection

I have an amplifier kit, in which it requires a power supply with +24v -24v and ground, the input is and audio jack which is +v and ground , i.e. both of these grounds are connected, i would be using a laptop charger to test the circuit as it needs minimum 19v but the charger has a pin in which i believe there is a + and a ground or - I dont know how to connect the power supply to the circuit as the cirxuit has 3 inputs(+,-,ground) and my power supply has just 2 outputs(+,- or ground) Im pretty new to the +,-,and ground concept and i am confused if i need to connect the - to the ground or not
This question is reposted from sound.stackexchange which was off-topic

Comment: You must make all electrical connections. BTW, the question is off-topic here.

Comment: I did not know where to post it. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "ground" in an electrical circuit is *always* a relative term: in fact, it's the "reference" from which every other voltage is measured. <sup>*</sup>

So, if you have `+24V`, `Gnd` and `-24V`, that means that if you were to measure the voltage between `-24V` and `+24V` you would measure 48V. In fact, if you were to go through all of the documentation and add `24` to all of the voltages, you'd get *exactly* the same circuit, with `0V`, `24V` and `48V` everywhere. That would make the novice happier - but confuse the professional no end! A usual audio signal rises and falls above and below some reference point (usually called "Ground"), so you'll get positive and negative voltages.

Your laptop power supply, that has `0V` and `19V`, fits inside the `Gnd` and `+24V` band. It doesn't work with the `Gnd` and `-24V` band at all. So you're going to need some kind of adapter or converter to get that to work.

> <sup>*</sup> Note that some circuits distinguish between "analog" ground and "digital" ground. That just means that analog signals reference against one ground, while digital signals reference against a different ground. The two grounds, if you measure the voltage between them, may not have any difference at all - but that's not guaranteed, and connecting the two may introduce interference, especially digital intereference on analog signals.

Comment: Thanks I was confused about it the whole time.A dding this as an answer